# AngularJS Where can i access the scope of a loaded controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Where can i access the scope of a loaded controller ? I like to have something like a event after the scope has been initialized for a controller to predefine the model for the view.

Is there something like `$rootScope.$on("$controllerLoaded")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not too clear, but it sounds like you want something to notify another part of an app after a particular controller is loaded. Is that correct?

If so, you have a couple options. Try looking into [`$emit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24emit). Essentially sends a signal to parent listeners.

Here is a [write-up of using `$emit` & `$broadcast`](http://motionharvest.com/2013/03/21/passing-arugments-to-on-in-angularjs-from-emit-and-broadcast/)

```
$rootScope.$on('emitName', function(){
    //do what you want
});
```

Another option (more of a hack) would be to set a flag at the end of your controller:

```
$rootScope.controllerLoaded = true
```

Then wherever you are wanting to know when it is done, simply check the `$rootScope.controllerLoaded` flag.

Comment: Not particular. Some controller.  $rootScope.$on("$controllerLoaded", controllerName);

Comment: just because you keep typing "$controllerLoaded" doesn't mean that it's a valid angular feature. It's not. You'd need to do one of the workarounds that I just described, or come up with another.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this inside your controller by assigning the value to `$scope`.

```
function GreetingCtrl($scope) {
    // a simple string
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';

    // something more complex
    $scope.myModel = {id:1, name:'bobby'};
}
```

You could then use this in your view:

```
<label>{{myModel.name}}</label>
```

Which would render a label with 'bobby' inside it (until you change your model and then the view is dynamically updated *automagically*).

Eventually your application will start to use real world data from a server store of some description and you will need to use either [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) to get at that data. Check each of the links for examples on how to initialise your model from these modules.

Check the [Controller documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) for more info

Comment: where can i predefine my model ?

Comment: @Abc - in the body of your controller. e.g. `$scope.myThing = {id:1, name: 'bobby'};`. You can then bind controls to your model using `{{myThing.name}}` for example which would output `bobby`. You will eventually be pulling your model from some server store and may want to look into [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) as a way of getting your model.. check the links for examples.